# Norm of the right shift operator in $B(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional separable complex Hilbert space.

Let $T \in B(H)$ be a unilateral weighted shift,

i.e. there exists an orthonormal basis $(e_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ for $H$ and a sequence $(w_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^{\infty}$ such that $Te_n= w_n e_{n+1}$.

Q: Write $\|T \|$ in terms of the sequence of weights $(w_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ for $T$.

Attempt:

So we have $\|T e_n\|= \| w_n e_{n+1} \|$.

$\|Te_n \|\leq | w_n| \| e_{n+1} \|$

i.e. $\|T \|\leq | w_n| $

On the other hand,

$\|T \|= \sup\{|Tx| : \| x\|=1 \} \geq |Te_n| = |w_n e_{n+1}| = |w_n| $

Thus, $\|T\| = |w_n|$.

Could you let me know if my work is correct?

Thank you!

Comment: The norm $||T||$ is equal to $\sup_n |w_n |$ and you should prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about your second inequality $||T|| \geq |w_n|$, but don't forget that it's true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. In the first part of your proof you have a logic mistake -- the equality $||T e_n|| = |w_n|||e_{n+1}||$ (and it's indeed an equality) implies only that $||T|| \geq |w_n|$ :) yes, again, because the norm of an operator is such number that the inequality $||Tx|| \leq ||T||||x||$ holds for all $x \in H$. Now that you now the answer from a comment, you should be able to prove that the last property of the norm is satisfied for it. Combine this with your second inequality which is true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and you'll get the result.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused about the first inequality . Why $\|Te_n \| \leq |w_n| \| e_{n+1}\|$ implies $\| T \| \geq |w_n|$?

Comment: because the norm of an operator is such number that the inequality $||Tx|| \leq ||T||||x||$ holds for all $x \in H$. If for $e_n$ $||Te_n|| = |w_n|||e_{n+1}|| = |w_n|||e_{n}||$, then $||T||$ can not be lesser, then $|w_n|$.

Comment: and the inequality $||T e_n|| \leq |w_n| ||e_{n+1}|| alone does not imply anything in fact, because we don't know if it is an optimal bound or not.

Comment: Does this make sense? $\| T\| = \| \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} w_n e_n\| \leq \| w_n \|_{\infty} \| \sum_n e_n\|= \| w_n\|_{\infty} = \sup |w_n |$? Thank you!

Comment: Not exactly, but you are close. Try the same for $||Tx||$ with arbitrary $x$ s.t. $||x|| = 1$ using the representation of $x$ via its Fourier series. You are welcome!