# Norm of operator acting on a basis vector in $l^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces

The problem reads:
Find the norm of an operator in $l^2$ defined as:

$$
Ae_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}e_{n+1}
$$

This is what I have done so far:

A acting on any $x\in l^2$ gives:
$$
Ax = A\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_ne_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}x_ne_{n+1}
$$
Therefore the norm would be:
$$
||A||=\sup_{||x||\le 1}||Ax|| = ||A||=\sup_{||x||\le 1}||\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}x_ne_{n+1}||=\sup_{||x||\le 1}|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}x_n|
$$
I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly or how to interpret the supremum in this case. Does this just give the norm to be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ or something else?

Comment: The last equality is false. What is the norm of an element in $\ell^2$ ?

Comment: This (in particular the comment) answers your question: [Norm of the right shift operator in $B(H)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4008725/norm-of-the-right-shift-operator-in-bh) See also this: [Copmute the norm of $n$-th iteration of a weighted shift operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4442395).